# How to loop over an array of variables with the same form of name?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe with a list of variables such as id_01-id_10.

I would like to loop over all variables to print a count plot for each variables (using seaborn as sns):

The expected output :

sns.countplot(id_01)

sns.countplot(id_02)

sns.countplot(id_03)

...

sns.countplot(id_10)

What is the syntax of such a loop ?
Thank you

Comment: Are `id_01`, `id_02` etc. individual *variables*? Or columns or such in the dataframe?

Comment: 'id_01' is the name of the first column, 'id_02' is the name of the second column, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do all the columns in your dataframe:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    sns.countplot(df[col])
```

. Otherwise, following the pattern in your question:

```py
for i in range(1,11):
    column='id_'+"{0}".format(i).zfill(2)
    sns.countplot(df[column])
```

that will go through the numbers 1-10 and set column to the correct column name. zfill will make sure that for single digit numbers, column equals id_01 rather than id_1.